# Display SVG element inline with Button element

Tags: html, css, svg, inline, display

I want to display an `<svg>` element in one line with an adjacent `<button>`.

I tried setting the svg's display property to inline or inline-block (even though i think thats default for svg), but it didn't work.
`float: left;` also doesn't work.

I still want the button to keep it's width of 100%, if that is possible.
Am I missing something?

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #4e4e4e;
}
.collapsible {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 18px;
 width: 100%;
 border: none;
 text-align: left;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 24px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover, .collapsible:active {
 background-color: #027bcb;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.content {
 margin: 10px 18px;
 display: none;
 overflow-x: scroll;
}

svg {
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 padding: 18px;
}

line {
 stroke:#027bcb;
 stroke-width:1
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<svg> <!-- this svg should be in line with the following button -->
 <line x1="12" y1="0" x2="12" y2="24" />
 <line x1="0" y1="12" x2="24" y2="12" />
</svg>

<button type="button" class="collapsible">Button here</button>

<div class="content">
 <p>some content</p>
</div>

<script>
 var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
 var line = document.getElementsByTagName("line");
 coll[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  var content = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (content.style.display === "block") {
   content.style.display = "none";
   line[0].style.stroke = "#027bcb";
   line[1].style.stroke = "#027bcb";
  } else {
   content.style.display = "block";
   line[0].style.stroke = "#ffffff";
   line[1].style.stroke = "#ffffff";
  }
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try using flexbox on the parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just have the `<SVG>` inside the `<button>` tag, here is a working snippet:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #4e4e4e;
}
.collapsible {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 18px;
 width: 100%;
 border: none;
 text-align: left;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 24px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover, .collapsible:active {
 background-color: #027bcb;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.content {
 margin: 10px 18px;
 display: none;
 overflow-x: scroll;
}

svg {
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
}

.collapsible:hover line {
  stroke: #fff;
}

line {
 stroke:#027bcb;
 stroke-width:1
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<button type="button" class="collapsible">

<svg> <!-- this svg should be in line with the following button -->
 <line x1="12" y1="0" x2="12" y2="24" />
 <line x1="0" y1="12" x2="24" y2="12" />
</svg>
Button here</button>

<div class="content">
 <p>some content</p>
</div>

<script>
 var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
 var line = document.getElementsByTagName("line");
 coll[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  var content = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (content.style.display === "block") {
   content.style.display = "none";
   line[0].style.stroke = "#027bcb";
   line[1].style.stroke = "#027bcb";
  } else {
   content.style.display = "block";
   line[0].style.stroke = "#ffffff";
   line[1].style.stroke = "#ffffff";
  }
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if i wrap the button and svg into a div, the js script for the collapsible doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Ok, Let me check.

Comment: @AbgrundLemur, I updated my check it now, please consider [accepting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find my answer useful :)

Comment: Thank You!! I think, placing a inline-block element (svg) inside an inline element (button) is semantically incorrect though. But it works, so I guess this is fine.

Comment: ok i found a way. wrapped the svg and adjacent button in a flex div, like you first suggested and changed my js from `var content = this.NextElementSibling` to `var content =this.parentElement.nextElementSibling`